# The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I am using https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js in application and made use of Viewer.js file and imported it in my js file. but this above error is displayed when i import this file. bpmn-js version 3.0.4.

Comment: i am getting this error for the json files inside bpmn-moddle\resources\bpmn\json

Comment: Just make sure JavaScript files are delivered as application/javascript